# Erase functionality on image objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am trying to make a sticker application.
One of the needed functionality is to erase the sticker.

I have been able to erase an image but how can i reduce the strength of the eraser?

Currently on touchesMoved function,

I am using this code:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:selectedFrame.imageView];

//erase part
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size, NO, 0);
[selectedFrame.imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size.width, selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),5);
CGContextClearRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 5, 5));
selectedFrame.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

This does erase the image properly but i want to reduce the eraser strength so it doesnt remove all the image on touch but reduces the opactiy of the image a bit.
Images attached below:
Current working functionality output -
http://cloudart.com.au/projects/appscreenshots/Erased_image.png

Required functionality output -
http://cloudart.com.au/projects/appscreenshots/app.png

Basically need to manage the eraser strength. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Following 2 Lines in your code can change your Eraser size**

Eraser size set to 5 pixel, Make any change in following 2 lines replace 5 with your size in given lines.

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),5);
CGContextClearRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 5, 5));
```

Comment: I am actually looking for eraser strength not eraser size. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: @vikrantRohilla what do you mean by `strength` here? would you pls elaborate.

Comment: By strength, i mean the eraser strength. I basically want to lower the eraser strength so if i erase a part of the image, it doesnt get completely removed but fades a bit away at that point where touched.

Comment: A good reference is in the app - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/animal-face-ig-photo-editor/id686038386?mt=8, where once you add a face, then if you try eraser. That will clear what the actual requirement is. Thanks for all the effort.

Comment: @vikrantRohilla then i think you should fill it will white color with less alpha instead `CGContextClearRect ` .

Comment: If i use whitecolor with less opacity, the erase doesnt work fine. Rather than erasing the image, it starts filling it with white color.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inputs but finally this worked for me -

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size, NO, 0);
    [selectedFrame.imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size.width, selectedFrame.imageView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),5);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    selectedFrame.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(eraseimg1.frame.size);
[eraseimg1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,eraseimg1.frame.size.width, eraseimg1.frame.size.height)];

CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ),kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ), 50);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);

CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastTouch1.x, lastTouch1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastTouch1.x, lastTouch1.y);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;
eraseimg1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```