# How to remove area of UIImage where user move his finger?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, crop

- **IMAGECROPPER**
- **UIGESTURE**
- **TOUCH**

Needed to achieve this, User selects Image and then cut it with Touch drag like `Photo Editing App.`

[image]

Comment: Instead of cutting it, just set draw a circle with the same fill color as the background color

Comment: User can add multiple images as overlay.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? Please show us what you have working.

Comment: No i don't , i am searching for a way to implement it. There may be multiple images and user can cut part of image from it with finger and add any new image as a layer on it. It will be like some art.
If you can suggest me any way to do this.

Comment: For now i got only one way 


        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: overlay.bounds)
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: rect))
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        overlay.layer.mask = maskLayer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457163/erase-functionality-on-image-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size)
            var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            drawImage.image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - 50))

            context?.move(to: fromPoint)
            context?.addLine(to: toPoint)
            context?.setLineCap(.butt)
            context?.setLineWidth(2)
            context?.setBlendMode(.clear)
            context?.setShouldAntialias(true)

            UIColor.clear.set()

            context?.strokePath()

            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
```